# Error when i parse string object to json object

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I'm trying to parse my string to a json object, it wont work, I get a error when I debug the code, Syntax error, here is my variable I want to parse,

```
var myyVar = "{title: 'myTitle',root: {id:'1',title:'CEO',subtitle:'John Doe',children: [{ id: '2',title: 'COO',subtitle: 'Steve Berman',type: 'staff'},{ id: '3',title: 'CTO',subtitle: 'Mark Claskov',type: 'staff'},]}}"

$.parseJSON(myvar);
```

I dont get any json objects in return

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the obvious difference in your variable name which I am assuming is a typo - try quoting your key fields.  eg:

```
var myVar = "{'title': 'myTitle'}
```